# Models getting out of hand

Tags: oop, laravel, laravel-5

We use laravel in our company and we follow 2 simple conventions:

1. Controllers should be thin.
2. Models represents database entities (user, roles, cars)

Now we're facing a dilemma: we have a screen where complicated data graphs are represented which require some long and heavy logic to produce. But where should we put all of this logic? controllers should be thin - so not in controllers. Models represent data entities, so it can't be model since this screen displays data from all of the other models but don't have an actual table/database entity. Services doesn't sound like a normal place.

I was wondering how did you approach similar situations

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Controllers should be as thin as possible"? I mean, you can't say "I want my car to weight maximum 2Kg and then build a monster truck".

Comment: Agreed, adding this logic to the controller was one of options that came up, but i wanted to consult with the good people of SO to see if there  approaches we didn't think about

Comment: I'm curious about other people's thought as well, as I'm not a laravel expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the logic into service. In service you can run other services (in case some logic is already in other service or if service is very complicated) and use repositories (or models in case you don't use any repositories). Of course there is no point to put big code or logic into controllers because they could run services which will return desired output.